# Delete a row in a specific table using Hibernate(ManyToMany relationship)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to make a follow/unfollow functionality in my project. Following function seems to work, but when I am using JpaRepository with intention to delete the follow-following relationship, it just removes rows from every table:

`Hibernate: delete from user_follow where follower=?
    Hibernate: delete from users_roles where users_id=?
    Hibernate: delete from user_follow where follower=? and following=?
    Hibernate: delete from users where id=?`

I wanted to make a unfollow method and a custom query for that in JpaRepository, but I don't know how to 'include' only the user_follow in JPQL query.

User class:

```
package com.paulthemenace.blog.models;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(length = 100)
private String fullName;

@Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 16, unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(length = 32)
private String password;

@OneToMany
private Set<Role> roles;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<Post>();

@Column
private String img;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "following")
private Set<User> follower;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_follow", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "follower"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "following"))
private Set<User> following;

public User() {
}

public User(String username, String password) {

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" + "id=" + id + ", username='" + username + '\'' + ", passwordHash='" + password + '\''
            + ", fullName='" + fullName + '\'' + '}';
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(String img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public Set<Post> getPosts() {
    return posts;
}

public void setPosts(Set<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
public Set<User> getFollower() {
    return follower;
}

public void setFollower(Set<User> follower) {
    this.follower = follower;
}

public Set<User> getFollowing() {
    return following;
}

public void setFollowing(Set<User> following) {
    this.following = following;
}

}
```

Controller:

```
package com.paulthemenace.blog.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.paulthemenace.blog.models.User;

import com.paulthemenace.blog.repositories.UserRepository;

@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

@RequestMapping("/users/{username}")
public String userProfile(@PathVariable("username") String user, Model model) {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    String name = auth.getName();
    User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(name);

    model.addAttribute("currentUser", currentUser);
    System.out.println(currentUser);

    User foundUser = userRepo.findByUsername(user);
    model.addAttribute("user", foundUser);
    return "/users/profile";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/follow/{username}")
public String follow(@PathVariable("username") String user, Model model) {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    String name = auth.getName();
    User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(name);

    model.addAttribute(currentUser);
    User foundUser = userRepo.findByUsername(user);

    currentUser.getFollowing().add(foundUser);
    model.addAttribute(foundUser);
    userRepo.save(foundUser);

    return "/users/profile";

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/unfollow/{username}")
public String unfollow(@PathVariable("username") String user, Model model) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User foundUser = userRepo.findByUsername(user);
    String currentUsername = auth.getName();
    User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(currentUsername);
    model.addAttribute(foundUser);
    model.addAttribute(currentUser);

    if (currentUser.getFollowing().contains(foundUser)) {
        currentUser.getFollowing().remove(foundUser);
        userRepo.delete(foundUser);
    }

    return "/users/profile";
}

}
```

UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
User findByUsername(String username);

}
```

user_follow table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_follow` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`follower` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`following` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`subscribed` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `follow_unique` (`follower`,`following`),
KEY `FK25l58y1y8ea2e93o068eqcpcs` (`following`),
CONSTRAINT `FK25l58y1y8ea2e93o068eqcpcs` FOREIGN KEY (`following`) 
REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK4cnml690o1hgbjwnhywknu8rx` FOREIGN KEY (`follower`) REFERENCES 
`users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=98 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: 1. Why does your join table have a, id and a subscribed column? They will always be null if you use that table as a join table for a ManyToMany. 2. Why do you call `userRepo.delete(foundUser);`. You don't want to delete a use, do you?

Comment: what do you mean it will always be null? userRepo.save(foundUser) inserts the data correctly when i call it. i called the delete() method hoping it'll do the magic for me, after the long time i spent on writing incorrect JPQL queries :)

Comment: 1.I missed the fact that the two columns are autogenerated. So they won't be null. But still: since they're not mapped, your app will never know what the values are, so they're useless. Deleting a user will do just that: deleting the user. You don't want to delete a user, so don't call that method. Make your controller transactional, and all you need is `currentUser.getFollowing().remove(foundUser);`.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.

Comment: For a bit of performance, get rid of `id` in `user_follow` and promote the `UNIQUE` to `PRIMARY`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you should not delete the user entity, you should update or save it.

```java
if (currentUser.getFollowing().contains(foundUser)) {
    currentUser.getFollowing().remove(foundUser);
    userRepo.save(foundUser);
}
```